# How to put multiple sets of data onto one graph using ggplot in R

Tags: r

I know this question has been asked multiple times, but I think because I'm using other elements (like `geom_smooth`) that this isn't working for me. I'm trying to plot three sets of data onto one graph.

the data frame would look similar to this (an example, as I cannot provide values for this private dataset):

```
group   x   y   SE
Control 1   5   1
Control 2   6   1
Control 3   9   1
GroupA  1   4   1
GroupA  2   7   1
GroupA  3   11  1
GroupB  1   2   1
GroupB  2   4   1
GroupB  3   9   1
```

This is the code for just one of the three data sets.

```
plot <- data [data$group == "Control", ]
p <- ggplot (plot, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(shape= 21, fill= "blue", colour= "black", size=2) +
  geom_smooth(method= "lm", se= FALSE,  colour= "red", formula=y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=y-SE, ymax=y+SE), width=.9)
p
```

The other two data sets are GroupA, and GroupB, SE is the standard error precalculated.

Right now this plots only the graph for the Control, I've tried melt but I'm just not sure how to melt it to get it to produce three graphs for Control, GroupA, GroupB with the lines of fit being different colors.

Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By using `plot <- data [data$group == "Control", ]` you are subsetting only that data. If you want to plot all three.
2. If you add the group within the aes it should plot the different lines.. 
   p <- ggplot (plot, aes(x, y, group=group))

Comment: thank you! I knew it was something simple like this :) My other question is how do I make the lines different colors? They are all showing up red.

Comment: @Purrina, you are using `colour = "red"`, so why shouldn't the lines be red? Consider reading an introductory text about `ggplot`, e.g. http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/

Comment: @Purrina, great! In the [section about lines in the tutorial](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Bar_and_line_graphs_%28ggplot2%29/#line-graphs_1), you find that you 'map' the colours of the lines to a particular variable by adding `colour = the-name-of-the-grouping-variable` in the `aes` argument. Good luck!